# axios: Is it possible to not hardcode HTTPS protocol from the link

Tags: axios

Is it possible to not hardcode HTTPS protocol in axios?
I would like to connect with HTTPS protocol without hardcoding.

```
axios.post('https://example.com/api/user', {
    firstName: 'Fred',
    lastName: 'Flintstone'
  })
```

EXPECTED

```
axios.post('example.com/api/user', {
    firstName: 'Fred',
    lastName: 'Flintstone'
  })
```